# packages = body.filter(function(pack) { in use atom ide

Tags: atom-editor

I have problem to use atom IDE
I can't install package in atom i got error :
\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60
packages = body.filter(function(pack) {
^
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxlcW.png)

I could not resolve this problem

Comment: Atom-Editor has been replaced by Pulsar-Edit.